# how to load Css in pdf using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

For my rails 4 app i want to convert html and Css into a pdf file.
i use the wkhtmltopdf and wicked_pdf gem
if i use the wicked helper it doesn't show the css but it render only the text

in my controller i have:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "#{@card.name}",
            :template => 'cards/show.html.slim',
            :page_size => "A4",
            :disposition => 'attachment'
```

And in the show.html.slim

```
    = link_to "Download PDF", :action => "show", :format => :pdf
```

aplication.html.erb

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf" -%>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've never seen `-%>` before. Is it meant to be like this, or is it mistyped?

Comment: i know, i tried both but -%> is what the documentation says.. https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Comment: It's most apparently mistyped... As for the rest, you don't write `"pdf"`, I think: You should use them to replace the helpers `javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag` ( I think, again )

Comment: edit code^*  application.html.erb

Answer (score 11):

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "css_file_name" -%>
```

this is the css file name which you must have in your **`app/assets/stylesheets/`** directory

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "css_file_name" -%>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

hope this might help you.

Comment: My application.SomeNum.css gets created in public folder. In this scenario, how do I handle? Also the file name is a random num.

Comment: In my example _css_file_name_ is a _scss_ and I use `@import "bootstrap.min"` for import my bootstrap file present in _vendor_ folder